# Votes do not appear to be reflected when viewing review tasks from review task history

Tags: bug, review, voting

I recently down voted an answer (on Arqade) as indicated by this screenshot (downvote arrow is blue):

[image: blue downvote arrow]

This answer was also previously in the Low Quality Posts review queue, but it is now only viewable from the history of the queue since the review task has been completed [found here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/320033).  The down vote arrow no longer indicates that I voted on this item when I navigate to the review task for the post:

[image: review item]

This seems to be the case for questions and answers and for all queues (I tested low quality and close vote queues).  If I try to vote again from the completed review task, it will update the number of votes and the arrow will be colored (example is from another post that I **also** downvoted previously outside of a queue.  At the time of posting, this question had a score of -6, one of those down votes being from me already):

[image: question downvote from review task]

**Note that this doesn't actually update the votes**. This appears to be client side only. Also note that this gif was edited to exclude the reviewers, but it is in fact from the review task.

The answer I down voted was also edited since my down vote.  Because of that, I believe this toast message will also display but I am not sure:

[image: toast message]

In this case, my vote was rejected, however the arrow initially doesn't indicate that I voted at all.  This also re-triggered the -1 reputation notification, though I did not lose any actual reputation for my "duplicate" vote.

Comment: Can you open browser dev tools to verify whether or not a request is getting sent when you vote from a queue? I can't repro this; for me, voting in a queue [sends a proper request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfW5u.gif), and I can see it reflected both outside the queue and upon returning to the review item after a refresh.

Comment: @zcoop98 is that review item you tried **completed** or still in progress? I think this works as expected for items still in progress.

Comment: You're right! That's the difference, I was trying it on an in-progress one.

Comment: @zcoop98 it does look like a request is made though still - and it comes back as successful, but the numbers don't match up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRewe.png