# Don't let me do fake downvote in LQP queue history's review task

Tags: bug, review, down-votes

I was going through my review history and clicked on a recent review task link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/86500

> [image]

Though I had previously downvoted this post, the downvote is not shown. There are bugs similar to this and I'm not reporting that.

I was able to downvote once again in the task page, but if I refreshed the webpage, the vote count is back to original.

After waiting for sometime, I tried the same again. This time I got an error saying that my vote is locked.

> [image]

So, the bug I wanted to report is: don't let me do fake downvote (perhaps, since my vote is not locked).

Comment: Did you check a browser cache?

Comment: @AugustoVasques No. How do I check that?

Comment: Duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381942/votes-do-not-appear-to-be-reflected-when-viewing-review-tasks-from-review-task-h  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377682/completed-review-item-does-not-show-whether-you-voted-or-followed-the-post-anymo